# Translation of 面倒 as referring to a person

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm trying to think of a good translation for the word 面倒 when used to refer to a person in a negative way, as in:

あんたは面倒なタイプの人間だ

The context is someone who is being very talkative and persistently debating a certain point, to the extent they are referring to their own speech as 屁理屈.

I can think of a bunch of related words, but nothing really seems to sound just right: annoying, troublesome, tedious, detail-oriented, argumentative, anal, etc.

You can see it used in context [here](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n2337dj/3/) if needed.

This is my best guess so far. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

```
You're one of those annoying argumentative people.
```

Comment: How about douc**bag?

Comment: Hmm... I did consider some insults like that, but I think they are overly generic. Also I'd prefer to avoid non-child-friendly words like your example.

Comment: Haha makes sense :P

Answer (score 2):

How about: You're one of *those* people.

Note the italics.

Comment: Not bad... Maybe the best translation so far.